# Configure ldap in grails 2.2.4 spring security core 2.0?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, ldap, grails-plugin

Im currently working on integration of my app with company ldap. While i was able to make application actually check users on ldap for authentication, users are not able to overcome spring security ROLES configuration. Im getting:
"Denied
Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page."
Every time i try to enter page that has @Secured(['ROLE_USER']) on it. I would like to know how to add every user on LDAP to have ROLE_USER so he will be able to fully use application.

My ldap configuration is pretty simple:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider','anonymousAuthenticationProvider','rememberMeAuthenticationProvider']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.anonymousReadOnly = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = "SOME LDAP ADRESS"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase = 'ou=Employees,O=*****,C=****'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'O=****,C=****'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchFilter = 'member={0}'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.attributesToReturn = null
```

And spring security core is default one:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'amelinium1.grails.SecUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'amelinium1.grails.SecUserSecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'amelinium1.grails.SecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/**':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/**/systeminfo':                 ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll']]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
```

Documentation provided on http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.pdf seems to be not up to date even if it is for 2.0 version of spring security core.
I've tried to implement Custom GrailsUser and GrailsUserDetailsService but they dont seem to blend with rest of the plugin.(implementation based on documentation).

Anyone could point me to right direction with some info about how to implement LDAP in newest version 2.0-RC2?

**EDIT**

My CustomUserDetailsService class, but im not sure if its right configuration for LDAP:

```
    class CustomUserDetailsService implements GrailsUserDetailsService{

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User.withTransaction { status ->

            User user = User.findByUsername(username)
            if (!user) throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', username)

            def authorities = user.authorities.collect {new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.authority)}

            return new CustomUserDetails(user.username, user.password, user.enabled,
                    !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired,
                    !user.accountLocked, authorities ?: NO_ROLES, user.id,
                    user.firstName, user.lastName)
        } as UserDetails
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        return loadUserByUsername(username);
    }

}
```

And CustomUserDetails class:

```
class CustomUserDetails extends GrailsUser{
        final String firstName
        final String lastName

        CustomUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
                          boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
                          boolean accountNonLocked,
                          Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities,
                          long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
            super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
                    credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities, id)

            this.firstName = firstName
            this.lastName = lastName
        }
    }
```

Problem is that i cannot get other informations from LDAP than username as ldap login.
Would appreciate help here also. After reworking application to beb ased on Customclasses im getting errors like :
No signature of method: static org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.findByUsername() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [hajduk]

Answer (score 5):

By default the Spring Security plugin gets user and role data from the database. The Spring bean that is responsible for reading the user and role data is named `userDetailsService`. If you want to get your user and role data from somewhere else - e.g. LDAP - you simply need to replace this bean with your own, e.g.

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.*
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException

class LdapUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        // load the user and their role(s) from LDAP by username and return their 
        // details as an instance of a class that implements the UserDetails interface
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register this class as a Spring bean in `resources.groovy`

```
userDetailsService(LdapUserDetailsService)
```

There are plugins that integrate Spring Security with LDAP, but I would prefer to do it myself given that it's so easy. The docs provide [an example](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html) of a custom `UserDetailsService`. Note that it's not necessary to extend any particular class when writing your own implementations of `UserDetailsService`/`UserDetails`, and for the purposes of debugging it's probably easier to just implement the interfaces directly.

Comment: Hey, thx for respond. Ive managed to overcome the problem with authentication with providing application my own implementationb of AuthoritiesPopulator for ldap as my ldap does not have own roles configured. something like this : ldapAuthProvider(org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider,
  ref("ldapAuthenticator"),
  ref("authoritiesPopulator")
  )
 
  authoritiesPopulator(amelinium1.grails.CustomAuthoritiesPopulator)

Comment: As for now users are able to login with ldap and use secured parts of application, but i would love to be able to map more ldap fields to my UserDetails class. Currently springSecurityService.getPrinsipal() returns only LOGIN for given user. But i would like to use some more like FirstName LastName, email etc. I have read from documentation i have to implement my own UserDetailsService and UserDetailsContextMapper and register them for ldapUserDetailsMapper, but i have no idea how to fetch data in default ContextMapper and forward it for rest of the classes. Any ideas about this problem ?

Comment: If you write your own implementation of `UserDetailsService` that returns a custom implementation of `UserDetails` you can map as many fields as you want to the latter. This is exactly what this example demonstrates: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/11%20Custom%20UserDetailsService.html. You can retrieve an instance of your `UserDetails` implementation for the current user by calling `springSecurityService.currentUser`

Comment: Ive added my custom classes but i don't really know how to fetch data from ldap in details class.

Comment: @user2761900 then post a new question asking how to do this