# Implementing simple ldap user details mapper - grails

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, ldap, grails-plugin

In my previous question i was working on adding roles to users logging from ldap. hopefully ive managed to register custom AuthoritiesPopulator for ldap. But now i would like to add some more functionallity to application and for that i need some more information about users than login-name.

Following this guide:
http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-ldap/docs/manual.106/guide/2.%20Usage.html

Im guessing i have to implement my own ldap details context mapper, and i did as shown below:

```
class CustomUserDetailsContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper {

   @Override
   public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
      // FETCHING DATA and ADDING ROLE
      return new CustomUserDetails(trueUsername, null, true, true, true, true, list, email)
   }

   @Override
   public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails arg0, DirContextAdapter arg1) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Only retrieving data from AD is currently supported")    
   }

}
```

And adding mapping in resource.config:

```
    ldapUserDetailsMapper(amelinium1.grails.CustomUserDetailsContextMapper)
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Application seem to use GormUserDetailsService to return User not the Context. Am i missing something here ?
Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you show your `CustomUserDetails`?

Comment: Here is the link to my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309762/configure-ldap-in-grails-2-2-4-spring-security-core-2-0